# Finding kernel for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having trouble understanding what it means to find the kernel of a matrix.

I have a matrix as follows and I need to determine the kernel.

$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ -1 & -1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$

I'm able to get the augmented matrix down to echelon form as follows.

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 4 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Where do I take it from here? What would the form of the solution be?

Would I just write a couple of equations like the following two?

$x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0$

$0x_1+5x_2+4x_3=0$

Comment: Yes. You see the solutions will depend on, say $x_3$, and setting $x_3=t$,  you will be able to write a solution as $t\times$ some fixed vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix-transformations/linear-transformations/v/preimage-and-kernel-example) Khan Academy video was the best resource for helping me understand this problem more.

In the end I wrote the following for my answer.

$x_1=-\frac{7}{5}x_3+\frac{1}{5}x_4$

$x_2=-\frac{4}{5}x_3-\frac{3}{5}x_4$

I wasn't certain how to express this with $t$, as Dovah-king and the video mentioned, because we have two free variables, unlike the example in the video.

Comment: $x = 0$ is not a free variable. In fact, it is not even a variable, as the equation $5x_2 + 4x_3 = 0$ shows.

Comment: The augmented matrix combines variables with constants to represent a system of linear equations, hence the name "augmented". The normal matrix approach would be to write the system of equations as $\boldsymbol{A} \vec{x} = \vec{b}$, where $A$ is a matrix and $b$ is a vector. Taking the inverse of A on both sides yields the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the kernel of a matrix $A$ is finding the **set** of vectors that, when multiplied by A, result in the vector $0$. (It is easy to verify that this set of vectors is a vector space)
Mathematically speaking, you must solve the equation:
$Ax = 0$, where $x$ is an vector.
Note that this equation might have one solution or *infinite* solutions. In the second case, you'll find, while solving the system, a *free variable*, for example, $x_2$. Then, your other vectors can depend of this variable. You will find a free variable if you find something like $0 x_2 = 0$. Notice that you can have more than one free variable. The number of free variables is also the dimension of the null space of a transformation $T$ defined by $T(x) = Ax$.

Notice that, in your case, you have that your 3rd line is null. This means that $x_3$ is your free variable. Call it $t$ and write the solution in terms of it.

Answer (score 0):

Let one of the variables, say $x_3$ be equal to $t$.

Then $5x_2 + 4t = 0, x_2 = -\frac{4}{5}t$ and $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = 0$ or $x_1 = -3t - 2 \cdot -\frac{4}{5}t = -\frac{7}{5}t$.

This means that $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \cr x_2 \cr x_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -7/5 \cr -4/5 \cr 1 \end{pmatrix} t$. We have parameterised all the variables in terms of a single parameter, which means the kernel has dimension $1$.

As a quick check using the rank-nullity theorem, $\text{dim} (\text{ker} (A)) + \text{rank}(A) = n$, which is indeed true as $1 + 2 = 3$.